# How to sample k random numbers in 0, 1, ..., n-1 without caching to an array

Tags: c++, random

I would like to sample k different (without replacement) random numbers in 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1.

It appears to me that most of the solutions that I could find online need an array that store all the numbers and then shuffle the array in some way. However, it takes O(n) space. I was wondering if there is any way in C++ without generating an array.

Comment: IMHO, the question is too broad. Showing what you have already done may help here.

Comment: If you are looking for really random numbers then you'll need to keep track of previously generated numbers to avoid duplicates. If you are looking just for a non-ordered sequence without dups then you can use something like [LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register).

Comment: I thought I had an implementation using *quadratic residues*.

Comment: Ah. Found something. See http://preshing.com/20121224/how-to-generate-a-sequence-of-unique-random-integers/

Comment: By "without generating an array", I mean in O(1) space. So the question becomes how to sample k distinct numbers in 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1 uniformly at random in O(1) space.

Comment: @CechCohomology: Did you take a look at the link I posted?

Comment: @Bathsheba, thanks! I am reading the link that you posted about quadratic residues.

Comment: @Bathsheba, it seems to me that the method of quadratic residues couldn't work for some given n (e.g., n is a composite number).

Comment: @CechCohomology; Yes, but you just set the range to the prime number greater than or equal to n - 1 and reject out of range values. Just check that doesn't introduce too much statistical bias though.

Comment: @Bathsheba I see. Many thanks!

Comment: If this were my project I'd trawl the internet for a few hours: surely someone has built this?

Comment: @Bathsheba please take a look at the answer - reservoir sampling should work here

Comment: Voted to reopen. There is nothing unclear here and I can’t see a duplicate. Sometimes there remains room for a flashback question to the early years of Stack Overflow. Remember we are building a Q and A site here.

Answer (score 2):

Sure

It is called [Reservoir Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). Basically, you pretend you're getting values 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1 from the stream, sample random number and exchange it with reservoir.

Used to be a pseudo-code, debugged it and now it should just work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

static int N = 0;
static int s = 0;

int next_item() { // emulate incoming with the stream

    if (s == N) // all values are streamed
        return -1;

    return s++;
}

std::vector<int> RS(int k) {
    std::vector<int> result;

    std::mt19937 rng(987654321);

    int sp = 0; // position in the stream

    for (;; ) {
        int v = next_item();
        if (v < 0)
            break;
        if (sp < k)
            result.push_back(v);
        else
        {
            std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(0, sp);
            int idx = uni(rng);
            if (idx < k)
                result[idx] = v;
        }
        ++sp;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    s = 0;
    N = 10000;
    auto v = RS(10);
    for (auto e : v) {
        std::cout << e << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```